# Insert multiple rows from xml feed with image url

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, import

I'm trying to insert multiple rows from xml feed, but only one row i get on refresh from more than 10 item in xml fedd, also the image row is null in table (thumb).

Any idea ? Thanks so much

> The PHP  code Look like this

```
<?php

$xmlReader = new XMLReader();

$filename = "data.xml";
$url = "http://www.autobazar.eu/software/david34114.php?table=records&pass=mixaEUieoi02Y";
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url));
$xmlReader->open($filename);

$host="localhost";
$username="";
$password="";
$db_name="";
$con=MySQL_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
MySQL_select_db("$db_name")or die("can not select DB");

$xmlReader->open($filename);

  while ($xmlReader->read())
    {
  switch ($xmlReader->name)
    {
  case 'item':

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$domNode = $xmlReader->expand();
$element = $dom->appendChild($domNode);
$domString = utf8_encode($dom->saveXML($element));
$item = new SimpleXMLElement($domString);

// Id server
$idserver = $item -> idserver;
// Slug
$type = $item -> title;
// Price
$price = $item -> price;
// Price sale
$price_sale = $item -> price;
// User ID
$user_id = $item -> user_id;
// Item title
$title = $item-> title;
// Brand nice_title
$nice_title = $item -> brand;
// Model
$model = $item -> model;
// Year
$modelyear = $item -> modelyear;

  if (strlen($item)> 0)
    {
      $query = "INSERT INTO listings (
        idx,
        nice_title,
        title,
        slug,
        price,
        price_sale,
        thumb,
        user_id,
        model_id,
        year
      )
        VALUES ('$idserver',
          '$title',
          '$nice_title',
          '$type',
          '$price',
          '$price_sale',
          '$image',
          '1',
          '$model',
          '$modelyear'
        )";
        MySQL_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' . MySQL_error());
         $conn->close();
      }
    }
  }
?>
```